# Problem where you must find a definite integral from information given about another definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

[image: ral]

I have though about u-subbing or just looking for similarities between the two integrals but those approaches seem to be getting me nowhere. I don't think I've seen a problem like this before, I am stumped. Help?

Comment: What $u$-sub did you try and show your work for your attempt.

Comment: Well first off can you tell that both integrals will be positive? (That eliminates some possibles) Then there is in fact an obvious substitution to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take $u=4-x^2 \Rightarrow du = -2x dx$ and if $x=1 \Rightarrow u=3,\, x=2 \Rightarrow u=0.$ Then

$$\int_1^2 xe^{\sin(4-x^2)}dx = \int_3^0-\frac{e^{\sin u}}{2}du = \int_0^3\frac{e^{\sin u}}{2}du = \frac{k}{2}$$